# How to download all attachments of all records of a custom object in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, lwc

I am new to file handling in Salesforce. I want to grab all the files attached to all the records of a custom object. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old-school SF used [`Attachment`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) object and you could simply go `SELECT Body, ContentType, Name FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = '...'`.

In Lightning there's high chance your attachments are called "Files" (the actual API name is `ContentDocument` / `ContentVersion`). Check if the attachment's ID starts with 068 or 069. They aren't linked directly to your record. Instead there's `ContentDocumentLink` table sitting in between, used to cross-share same file. (You upload it and waste database space once, then you can cross-link it in Chatter posts, groups, other records...)

The official [ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm) isn't great, try to click through it in Setup -> Schema Builder or this answer might help: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/160285/799. There's a sample query which you might have to fine-tune a bit, for example to `SELECT ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData` to get the actual payload.

Check out other questions around here about `ContentVersion`. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668673/313628 (it's other way around, about upload but should give you good idea).

Comment: P.S. If you have Email-to-Case there's chance there are Files that appear on the Case related list but their `ContentDocumentLink` links them to `EmailMessage`, not to `Case`. There's setup option that enables that. So maybe you need 2 queries, get Case and related Email ids, then all CDLs -> CDs -> latest file versions.

Answer (score 1):

AppExchange tool you can try for bulk download, Satrang Mass File Download AppExchange App helps to download Bulk of Files and Attachments from Standard and Custom Objects just within a few clicks.

URL - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsAOUAZ&tab=e

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the publisher of this Mass File Download AppExchange App.

Answer (score 0):

You can export all notes and attachments using open-source sfdx-hardis plugin command

- First, define a files export

`sfdx hardis:org:configure:files`

When prompted for SOQL request, you can input `SELECT Id,Name FROM YourCustomObjectName__c`

- Then, run the files export

`sfdx hardis:org:files:export`

More details in this [article](https://nicolas.vuillamy.fr/how-to-mass-download-notes-and-attachments-files-from-a-salesforce-org-83a028824afd)

[image]

*Disclaimer: My company authors sfdx-hardis plugin*